# Update elements by class in each Prototype selector result

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Ok, so i have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="a1" class="article">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p class="info"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="a2" class="article"></div>
  <div id="a3" class="article"></div>
  <div id="a4" class="article"></div>
</div>
```

The goal is to process each article and add info about it into the info p element. So I figured I'd loop through all the divs like this:

```
$$('.article').each(function(item,index){
   var info = $(item).select('p.info');
   info.update('<a>link</a> <p>Stuff about the article etc.</p>');
});
```

and write new content with update().
 It does not work, however, the error being that .update() is not a function. How would I do the update?

OK, results: T.J. Crowder hinted why it wasn't working, and I eventually came up with this code:

```
$(item).select('p.info')[0].update('Stuff about the article etc.');
```

Key point was in manipulating the first item of array returned by the select(), which then updated the info element as i wanted it to..

Comment: Actually, my point was that you can do this: `$(item).down('p.info').update('Stuff about the article etc.');` Element#down (link provided in my answer) looks in the element's descendants for the first (or nth, if you give it an index) descendant matching the given selector.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason i didn't get that to work. Probably my error though, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element#select` returns an array, not an element, but you're treating it like an element. You might want [`Element#down`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element.html#down-class_method) instead.